# How do I invert in Django the pretty "yes", "no" icons of a BooleanField in the Admin site?

Tags: python, django, boolean, django-admin, icons

When your model has a BooleanField, the Django Admin site displays circular icons:

- a green checkmark for "True"
- a red X for "False"

The Django docs call those icons ["pretty"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

> If the field is a BooleanField, Django will display a pretty “yes”,
> “no”, or “unknown” icon instead of True, False, or None.

**it looks great!** but my BooleanField is called "pending" so **if `pending = True` , I want Django Admin site to display a red X instead of a green checkmark**. *Because green means "good" and red means "bad"*. Most of my entries are not pending, so the list is full of red X icons, it looks bad, I want them to be mostly green checkmarks instead.

I know I could add a `def` in the model with a `return not self.pending` but that displays the words *"True"* and *"False"* instead, I want the icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `boolean=True` when define custom admin field like this

```
@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('pk', 'is_not_pending')

    @admin.display(description='Is not pending', boolean=True)
    def is_not_pending(self, obj):
        return not obj.pending
```